# Can no longer SSH to AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, networking, aws, amazon-ec2

We have an AWS EC2 instance running Amazon Linux 2. This instance was running fine up until a couple days ago.

Then we used an Ansible playbook to install a new version of our software. We have used this same playbook many times before without any problems. But this time, after the playbook said it successfully executed, we could no longer SSH to the instance. SSH outputs the following:

```
$ ssh -vvv -i .ssh/ourkey.pem ec2-user@10.130.35.176
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.130.35.176" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.130.35.176 [10.130.35.176] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.130.35.176 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 10.130.35.176 port 22: Connection refused
```

From the AWS console, we tried stopping the EC2 instance and restarting it, but we still cannot SSH to it.

It is not a security group issue, because I can SSH to another instance in the same VPC and subnet as the inaccessible instance. Both of those instances have the exact same security groups.

I found another [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/599141/180506) saying the problem might be caused by a corrupted `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. I detached the EBS volume from the inaccessible instance and attached it to another instance that I can SSH to. Then I compared the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on the volume to the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file of the instance that I am able to SSH to, and they are exactly the same.

I also looked at the `/etc/fstab` on the volume, since I saw other posts saying that might be the culprit, but it seems okay:

```
#
UUID=ec9a77e7-7b7b-4421-a91c-9142206a844a     /           xfs    defaults,noatime  1   1
```

I also looked for sshd logs and the only ones I could find were in /var/log/secure:

```
Dec  4 19:21:33 ip-10-130-35-176 sshd[3265]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Dec  4 20:10:23 ip-10-130-35-176 sshd[3280]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Dec  4 20:10:23 ip-10-130-35-176 sshd[3280]: Server listening on :: port 22.
```

In the AWS console, on the EC2 instance, under Actions > Monitor and troubleshoot > Get system log, there is a line saying the SSH daemon started:

```
Started OpenSSH server daemon.
```

It also shows a login prompt, so the instance seems to be up and running:

```
Amazon Linux 2
Kernel 5.10.96-90.460.amzn2.x86_64 on an x86_64

ip-10-130-35-176 login:
```

One thing I cannot do is connect to the instance using the AWS console. The EC2 Instance Connect, Session Manager, and EC2 serial console methods do not work on our instance.

I also saw a post where someone suggested to try telneting to it, but that didn't work either:

```
$ telnet 10.130.35.176 22
Trying 10.130.35.176...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

The only thing I can do is to mount the EBS volume on another EC2 instance that I can SSH to. What else can I look at to see why I cannot SSH to this instance?

Comment: Any firewalls that could have been installed ? Since you can access `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, try changing the ssh port from 22 to something else then try connecting to that port.

Comment: When you mounted the EC2 instance's root filesystem on another EC2 instance, did you check how full the filesystem is?  A full disk can prevent users from logging in.

Comment: @SottoVoce The filesystem is only 53% full.

Comment: @mittal I changed the port to 10049, and also added a security group to allow TCP to port 10049, but I still get a connection refused.

Comment: Is ANY traffic getting through? You say you can't SSH, but there is no layer-2 troubleshooting listed in your question. Can you PING? What does NMAP syn etc. port-scan report as open/listening? IS there any other port or service open on the instance? It doesn't look like packets are flowing...
`debug1: connect to address 10.130.35.176 port 22: Connection refused` and 
`ssh: connect to host 10.130.35.176 port 22: Connection refused`